# How to resize menu with css

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive

I want my right aligned horizontal menu to shrink to a certain extent when resize the browser. But after a certain size, it should be stay absolute or constant like [in this site.](https://templates.cms-guide.com/58746/) I am new in CSS so I couldn't find the correct solution for this. I don't know whether I should use the js. Is it possible to do this with css?

[Here is jsfiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/kokolos/Lbev7t8a/2/)

This is what I did:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header1 {
  background-image: url("header_bg.jpg");
  height: 580px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 55% 45%;
}

.header2 {
  height: 580px;
  background-color: white;
}

.header3 {
  height: 580px;
  background-color: #E4EBF5;
  background-image: url("pc.jpg");
}

.header4 {
  height: 200px;
}

.header5 {
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("köprü.jpeg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: 0.95;
}

.header6 {
  height: 600px;
}

.navbar1 {
  height: 88px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.imglogo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 175px;
  top: 32px;
}

a.ad {
  position: absolute;
  left: 215px;
  top: 22px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  transform: perspective(0.1px) scale(1.0);
  /****** çok iyiiiiiiiiiiiiiii. smooth text effect!!! ******/
}

.çizgi {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 0px #F2595B;
}

ul.menu {
  padding-left: 980px;
  height: 88px;
}

ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 17px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12.4px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  line-height: 88px;
}

ul.menu ul {
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

ul.menu>li ul ul {
  top: 30px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 180px;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out 300ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out 300ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out 300ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out 300ms;
}

ul.menu>li:hover {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 0px #F2595B;
}

ul.menu ul li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out 300ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out 300ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out 300ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out 300ms;
}

.yazzı {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 47px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  top: 190px;
}

.yazzı2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  top: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oylesine.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header1">
    <div class="navbar1">

      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="çizgi"><a href="">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Our services</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Events</a>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Set up</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Marketing</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="">Prices</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>


      <img src="logo.png" class="imglogo" alt=""> <a href="" class="ad">MailJet</a>
    </div>




    <div class="yazzı">
      <p> Meet The Mail Jet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="yazzı2">
      <p> The Best Mail Service On The Web!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
      <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="header2"></div>
  <div class="header3"></div>
  <div class="header4"></div>
  <div class="header5"></div>
  <div class="header6"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

What can I do?

Comment: use media query for this it will help you for make your page responsive  check the link                 https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Ok but how to shrink my menu when shrink the page? Or how can I scroll the menu left when page is shrinked? Like in this site [link](https://templates.cms-guide.com/58746/)

Comment: use media query for specific resolution i.e 800px  and add menu css code into in it change the css in that particular resolution i.e for 800px for e.g https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery check th link you will understand that where you want to change

Comment: you want your menu will shift to the left side of your window when page is shrinked

Comment: yes exactly, that's what I want. But my menu is work like overflow:hidden

Comment: Its not possible at all.. Not only for menu the overall page are hided on particular size.. How you build this page? Is this any js used??

Comment: @Manikandan2811 I didn't use any js. I am actually new at web site making. Where should I start?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 Okay I've started from the responsive design and I did it. Thanks for saying that it was impossible.

Answer (score 0):

On your menu CSS you can try using both width and max-width.

Eg

```
.menu{
width: 400px;
max-width :85%;
}
```

This will mean that your width will be 400px,but if your screen width gets narrow enough the max width will take effect and your menu will only take 85%.

You can also utilise min-width etc.